# Not to mean no-brainer

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus

[image: image description to be deciphered]

1. What does this picture mean?
2. What are meant by different component of this picture?
3. What is indicated by the square inside the red bevelle?

Answer need to contain explanation.

Hint1:

> Hint1 : it is simpler. Mathematical ciphers not required.

Hint2:

> The second-outermost : Look for word association intentionally omitted.

Hint3:

> Forget about all texts and look at the lines. What appears in mind in simple way?

Hint4:

> The number trio (138, 154, 91) is associated with computer.

Hint5:

> To solve central red bevelle, observe other segments.

Hint 6:

> Wordplay tag is important

Edit: I was not aware of puzzling etiquette/ community rules of hinting and answering, thanks for guiding me.  so right now I'm not publishing the full answer (and I wish I could unpublish the partial answer). Any attempt to solve will be greatly appreciated.

Hint6:

> "Direction" of something is important.

Comment: Rot13(Gur pbearef ercerfrag Syhbevar, Puybevar, Oebzvar, Vbqvar (pybpxjvfr) zrnavat unybtraf. [9, 17, 35, 53].)

Comment: Pneoba naq obeba ner gur bayl oynpx ryrzragf nppbeqvat gb [element properties](https://periodictable.com/Properties/A/Color.html). Fperj vf znqr sebz fgrry. Vg nyfb unf pneoba. Fb, oynpx zrnaf pneoba. Vg vf nyfb znqr sebz veba juvpu vf n zrgny. Fb, zhfvp vzcyvrf zrgny zhfvp. Fb, zrgny. Oyraq ercerfragf gur nyybl. Fgrry vf na nyybl bs veba, pneoba naq puebzvhz. Fb, gur vaare obk vf fgrry, puebzvhz, veba, pneoba. V thrff.

Comment: Vf (138,154,91) ETO pbybe pbqr?

Comment: Are you sure that [tag:cryptic-clues] is correct? It refers to a specific type of crossword clue where the goal is to parse the clue as definition and wordplay.

Comment: @JohnBrookfields Yes it is right

Comment: @JohnBrookfields You are very close to answer

Comment: ROT13 Jung pbybhe vf gung? Jurer vg znl or sbhaq?

Comment: @Deusovi I have removed cryptic tag. And the question is not about crossword

Comment: @AlwaysConfused, vg vf zbff terra. Zbff pna or sbhaq va sberfgf naq jbbqynaqf bs pbhefr.

Comment: @ You are half done. You may attempt make an answer

Comment: Lrf vg vf terrarel be tenffrf be ohfurf

Answer (score 2):

Am publishing answer but will accept newcoming answer.

Whole picture:

> Does it look like a landscape of a PARK?

Outermost Layer:

> F, Cl, Br, I means HALOGEN group of elements. This is to hint there are 4 HALOGEN LAMPS at the corner of the park. And as user @John Brookfields correctly pointed out; the number is an RGB code to indicate moss green i.e, there are vegetation.

Next layer

> The word PITCH goes with SCREW (Screw-pitch), MUSIC (Pitch of a sound), PITCHBLEND (a mineral), and PITCH-BLACK. so this layer indicate a PITCH ROAD. There is a road within the landscape which is covered by pitch.

3 small rectangles:

> 1 - 9 - eat. The 19th letter of English Alphabet is S. So together it is SEAT. There are some seats within the park.

Inner large rectangle:

> The 3 numbers again denote vegetation. There are grass, trees, mosses etc. in the park.

The inner red bevelle-

It is kind of rebus and I think it is easy one. I will tell the solution few hours later.

Hint:

> Do you notice some similarities in all the layers?

Comment: Can I ask why you've published (most of) the answer already? Your q was posted only 14 hours ago and on a weekend when site traffic is usually much lower. Your post will likely not even have been seen yet by most of the active members of what is an international global community, based in many different timezones. Please remember there is never any rush to post the intended solution - it just takes time for people to spot the question, work out the answer and post it (and that could be days or weeks later). In general, give us more time and you'll enjoy watching people work on your puzzle :)

Comment: @Stiv I did not assume a rush but I felt like it is unfair to hold a solution for too long. I am sorry if it violate community standards. Do I need to delete this answer?

Comment: No need to apologise - it's just a learning process as to how this community works :) The key thing to realise is that *there is no shame in having an unsolved puzzle*. It's very normal for an enigmatic puzzle of this nature to take several days before it clicks for somebody (although John in comments looked like he was onto something already), and sometimes it's a good idea to add a small hint after 2 or 3 days to give solvers a helping hand. It's your choice whether to delete it or not. Note though that anything deleted can still be viewed by users above a certain rep level.

Comment: @Stiv Thank you for taking time to type detailed comments to communicate. Okay this time I am retaining the answer but from next time I will be more cautious. An other reason I was worrying if I have made the puzzle too bad/unlikely to guess. I tend to overthink a lot.

Comment: No problem :) That overthinking is a natural tendency shared by a lot of people! And the worry about making the puzzle unguessable (again very natural) could probably be helped by editing in a little hint every 2-3 days as above... The most important thing is to *enjoy* making your puzzles and being part of this community. Happy Puzzling! :)